I can’t pass a treshold no matter what I do
I am currently training an CNN for classification. My training data are 80x80 images, 3 channels, which I have grouped into 25% validation, 75% training, all evenly distributed. I have 3 classes into they are grouped by. On top of that, I reserved the same amount of data as validation for testing.
The problem appears with the validation and overall results for the model. I have tried many approaches like changing the complexity, changing the batch size, optimizer, epochs, learning rate and so on, but I can t pass the 60-70% validation accuracy which further results in 65% accuracy on testing data.
I know that my model overfits, but none of the techniques that I have found online worked for me ( data augmentation, robust model, …).
It reaches the peak of training in any model, but no matter how hard I push and change the parameters, it won t affect the overall accuracy of the model.
Any info or suggestion that could help me or at least give me a clue.
I will list a plot with the best accuracy that I have got along with the model and the hyper parameters.
Some explanation of choosing them:

batch size of 512 was the best result for my machine; for what I have read the bigger the batch, the better the results should be
Adam is the best optimezer for all general use cases and also I don't know how to correctly adjust the parameter for SGD and if it is worth trying
I dindn't implemeted an early stopping mechanism, due to the small size of the model, I could watch and decide when to end the training, sometimes even let it overfit so I can plot the graph more correctly


tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(80, 80, 3)), # 80x80x3
tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("vertical"),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')

After seeing this I know what you probably thinking...Why would't I increase the number of input data or added dropout? I did, and was the same or even worst.
So please if the above is to little to pronounce, ask more questions. Thank you in advance!

Could you share what the task is? Also, do you have reported accuracy on same or very similar task from a paper, or when compared to human performance on the task? These are important details, because maybe there's a change in approach that could help, but also maybe 70% accuracy on this task is a realistic best possible result

@NeilSlater The task is to clasify the images into 3 classes, they are not really well defined (as, for example: dog, cat, elephant), but a more abstract ones, you could even say they are just grouped, reather than classified. As for accuracy, it is reported for the same task. I only can reach the peak ok ~70% no matter what I try. As I saw others results on the same task, it can peak 80-85% accuracy. So yeah...There's plenty of optimization to be done, but I can't find the right tunning for it.
